# How can I make an attractive enclosure for my circuit?

Tags: design, enclosure

I have finished working on the circuit and firmware for my design of a MIDI controller. I'd now like to take it off the breadboard and put it inside some sort of enclosure. I can handle making the PCB, but I really have no idea about how to go about making an attractive enclosure?

The circuit has a 16 button grid and 2 potentiometers on it and a USB connection. I saw the design of the [Midi fighter](http://store.djtechtools.com/midi-fighter.html) and really liked it. I looked at Radioshack and saw they had some cheap looking boxes, but that's not really what I was looking for.

Is there some sort of resource or pointers to how to do attractive enclosure design?

Comment: Have you looked at the [tag:enclosure] or [tag:cases] tags?

Comment: You came to the wrong place.  We're engineers.  We don't do attractive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My two favorite places are [OKW Enclosures](http://www.okwenclosures.com/) and [Polycase](http://www.polycase.com/).  They have off the shelf options in different styles, no minimum order.  They will even do customization on small orders too, i.e. drill holes, silkscreen, etc.

If you can't wait and you are lucky enough to live next to a Fry's electronics, you can walk over and pick up a simple one for not much extra overhead.

Answer (score 1):

[Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/) has a lot of stuff about making cases.

I used once a plastic laminate called "Forex", which is used in advertisement and is very easy to craft. Unfortunately, googling it gives a lot of results for "Foreign Exchange" or something similar.

You can also try in the [home improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) site here; it's about DIY stuff, I don't know anything more.